# MVC DisplayTemplate does not display C# string variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My main model, called Project, has two variables of type Address which is a class I defined. Since I wanted dynamic formatting of addresses based on which fields were defined. The code for my DisplayTemplate is:

```
@model ProjectClearanceApp.Models.Project.Address

@{
    string addr = "";
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Line1))
    {
        addr += (Model.Line1 + "\n");
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Line2))
    {
        addr += (Model.Line2 + "\n");
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.City))
    {
        addr += Model.City;
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.State))
    {
        addr += (", " + Model.State);
    }
    if (Model.ZipCode != 0)
    {
        addr += (", " + Model.ZipCode);
    }
    Html.Raw(addr);
}
```

The reason I'm using a string variable and appending to it is because I originally had my display template defined as:

```
@model ProjectClearanceApp.Models.Project.Address

@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Line1))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Line1)
    <br />
}
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Line2))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Line2)
    <br />
}
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.City))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City)
}
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.State))
{
    @:, @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.State)
}
@if (Model.ZipCode != 0)
{
    @:, @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ZipCode)
}
```

but because the last three DisplayFor's are on separate lines (at least that's my thought, I could be wrong), the addresses would display as `FakeCity , FakeState , 12345` with a space before each comma (if someone has a quick fix for that, that would solve all my problems).

However when I use the string it just does not display the variable at all on my page. I set a breakpoint on the last line (`Html.Raw(addr);`) and `addr` has the correct value when my code gets to that point in processing the addresses, but when it renders the page itself, nothing shows up. I've tried `Html.Display(addr);` and `Html.DisplayText(addr);` but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a leading `@` to `Html.Raw()`. Without that your just executing the method, not returning its value and outputting the result it generates.

```
@model ProjectClearanceApp.Models.Project.Address
@{
    string addr = "";
    ....
    @Html.Raw(addr); // add leading `@`
}
```

Comment: Even though the whole block of code is wrapped with `@{ ... }`?

Comment: Yes :) - did you try it?

Comment: I won't be in front of the code again until tomorrow but I'll let you know if it works!